# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Индекс и длина должны указывать на позицию в строке. Имя параметра: length"

Tags: c#

Суть приложения была в том чтоб она эмитировала эффект печатающей машинки, но по окончанию выдает ошибку. Как быть с этим?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {

        string text = "рок в разделе 1.10.32";
        int countEntered = 0;
        Timer t = new Timer() { Interval = 350 };
        t.Tick += (s, _) =>
        {
            textBox.Text = text.Substring(0, ++countEntered);
        };

        t.Start();

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: А как быть программе? Которой говорят вырезать из строки подстроку большей длины, чем оригинал. Как?!

Comment: Товарищ хотел сказать, что вам необходимо остановить инкремент, когда countEntered станет больше длины строки.

Comment: Ааа, теперь поняла, но проблема в том что для меня все равно остается загадкой как так как только приступила к изучению данной функции, я нахожу много вариаций как остановиться таймер, но он ни как не подходят под мой код. Я понимаю что это моя проблема и то что я не могу разобраться сама поэтому и написала сюда, что ткнули пальцем так сказать.